# Mixing abstract & public/private in class declaration

Tags: java, eclipse

There is given `prr` class with `public abstract prr()`.
According to official java documentation shouldn't be possible to write abstract & private keyword together, but it compile in Eclipse

```
abstract class prr {
/* we have an abstract class as prr. There is a method as show.*/
abstract private void show();
}
// Since show() is abstract, this is redefined in App class.
// Ideally show() should not even be seen in App because it is private.
public class App
{
private void show(){
    System.out.println("Inside prr");}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    App m = new App();
    m.show();}}
```

The output is:

> Inside prr

How it's possible to compile it under eclipse that is should not supported according to docs?

Comment: App is not extending from prr so the show method in App has nothing to do with the show method in prr. Also please add a reference to the documentation that you refer to.

Comment: You are simply calling the show() method in App without extending prr or overriding show() in prr (which you can't do anyaway because it is declared private).  Even if you declared show() in prr public, you still couldn't override in in App without extending prr

Comment: Your `prr` class does not compile in Eclipse Oxygen - "The abstract method show in type prr can only set a visibility modifier, one of public or 
  protected"

Comment: Every time you say "as per java docs", _quote from it_, please.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods cannot be inherited from a super class. An abstract method has to be overridden and implemented in the derived class. Since private methods cannot be inherited, it makes no sense to declare an abstract method which is private. Either make that abstract method `public` or `protected`

Private method means private to the class where its defined.

You can modify your code like this:

```
abstract class Prr {
    protected abstract void show();
}

public class App extends Prr {
    @Override
    void show() {
        System.out.println("Inside prr");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        App m = new App();
        m.show();
   }
}
```